# Laravel middleware not working with route group, when url segments are more than 1

Tags: laravel, routes, locale, middleware

[image: asdasd]

Here is my middleware

[image: asdasdas]

And here are the Routes

when I uncomment the `dd('asd');` from hande function in locale middleware it always works on all routes like `/asdasdasd` or some real link, but when the url segments are more than 1, it just shows 404, not the `dd(asd)` it's not even entering in that middleware, even with a right url like `programs/1`